# wpf application, populating a listview from entity framework table/view

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

Really simple request.  Just trying to populate a listview with data from an e.f. view called "testview".

Here's my markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Travel Requests" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="389,10,382,0"/>
    <Button x:Name="cmdFillListbox" Content="Fill listbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <ListView x:Name="lstRequests" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="166" Margin="70,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="588">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

And here's my vb code:

```
Private Sub getRequests()
    Dim r = New ITMSEntities
    lstRequests.ItemsSource = r.TestView.ToList
End Sub
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was this in my markup:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TravelRequestID}" />
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TravellerFullName}" />
```

Now it works well - hope this helps someone else too.  I'm amazed at googling this problem, and all the solutions I found on the internet were 100s of lines of code.